# How can I send an invoice for only some contribution pages?

Tags: contributions, invoice

I have five different contribution pages for different purposes. For one of them it makes sense to automatically issue an invoice, but not for the others. What's the best way to automatically issue an invoice for all transactions going through this one contribution page, but not any of the others?

Answer (score 3):

With little bit of custom coding via an extension it is possible to exclude invoice on certain conditions

Comment: Is it possible to use CiviRules to send an email with an invoice attached?